# Kendo gird vaildation does not appear

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo Grid validation not appear to other columns 
just appear for Color Column not that color column is 
custom edit dropdownlist.

the problem comes just for text box control so validation not fire when click edit or add button 
i tried to much things if you see edit function is commented if you tried it the validation will fire in all cases if there value in text box or not

```
   <script>
        function GridParams() {
            var json = {
                CompanyId: <%= CompanyId%>,
                LangParameter: "<%= LangParameter%>",
            };
            return json;
        }
        var Colors = [
            { text: 'Blue', value: "Blue" },
            { text: 'Green', value: "Green" },
            { text: 'Orange', value: "Orange" },
            { text: 'Yellow', value: "Yellow" },
            { text: 'Red', value: "Red" },
        ];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            kendo.ui.progress($(".chart-loading"), true);
            var d = $("#gvPerformanceRate").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: function (options) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                data: GridParams(),
                                url: "<%= ExtensionsClass.GetAppSetting("APIURL") %>/api/PerformanceRate/GetPerformanceRates",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (msg) {
                                    options.success(msg);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                    },
                    pageSize: 6
                },
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    kendo.ui.progress($(".chart-loading"), false);
                },
                filter: function (e) {
                    kendo.ui.progress($(".chart-loading"), true);
                },
                page: function (e) {
                    kendo.ui.progress($(".chart-loading"), true);
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: 'PerformanceRateId',
                        fields: {
                            PerformanceRateId: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            PerformanceRateValue: {
                                type: "string", editable: true, validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    validatePerformanceRateValue: function (input) {
                                        console.log("v");
                                        if (input.is("[name='PerformanceRateValue']") && input.val() == "") {
                                            input.attr("data-performanceratevaluevalidation-msg", "Performance Rate Value required");
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            PerformanceRateDescEn: { type: "string", validation: { required: true }, editable: true },
                            PerformanceRateDescAr: { type: "string", validation: { required: true }, editable: true },
                            Color: { type: "string", validation: { required: true }, editable: true },

                        }
                    }
                },
                filterMenuInit: function (e) {
                    $(e.container).css("width", "300px")
                },
                filterable: {
                    extra: false,
                    operators: {
                        string: {
                            startswith: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","Startswith").ToString() %>",
                            eq: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","IsEqualTo").ToString() %>",
                            neq: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","IsNotEqualTo").ToString() %>",
                            gt: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","After").ToString() %>",
                            lt: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","Before").ToString() %>",
                            isnull: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","Null").ToString() %>",
                            isnotnull: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","IsNotNull").ToString() %>",
                            gte: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","AfterOrEqualTo").ToString() %>",
                            lte: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","BeforeOrEqualTo").ToString() %>"
                        },
                    },
                    messages: {
                        info: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","FilterHeaderText").ToString() %>", // Sets the text on top of the Filter menu.
                        filter: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","FilterButton").ToString() %>", // Sets the text for the "Filter" button.
                        clear: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","FilterClear").ToString() %>", // Sets the text for the "Clear" button.
                        // When filtering Boolean numbers.
                        isTrue: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","isTrue").ToString() %>", // Sets the text for "isTrue" radio button.
                        isFalse: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","isFalse").ToString() %>", // Sets the text for "isFalse" radio button.

                        // Changes the text of the "And" and "Or" of the Filter menu.
                        and: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","And").ToString() %>",
                        or: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","Or").ToString() %>"
                    },

                },
                toolbar: ["create"],
                editable: {
                    mode: "popup",
                    //template: kendo.template($("#popup_editor").html())
                },
                scrollable: false,
                groupable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: [6, 9, 12, "All"],
                    buttonCount: 5,
                    messages: {
                        display: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","items").ToString() %>", //{0} is the index of the first record on the page, {1} - index of the last record on the page, {2} is the total amount of records
                        empty: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","empty").ToString() %>",
                        page: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","Page").ToString() %>",
                        of: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","of").ToString() %>", //{0} is total amount of pages
                        itemsPerPage: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","NumberOfEntries").ToString() %>",
                        first: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","first").ToString() %>",
                        previous: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","previous").ToString() %>",
                        next: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","next").ToString() %>",
                        last: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","last").ToString() %>",
                        refresh: "<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("GlobalResource","refresh").ToString() %>"
                    }
                },
                save: function (e) {
                    //console.log(e.model.isNew());
                },
                //edit: function (e) {
                //    var validator = e.container.getKendoValidator();
                //    var options = validator.options;
                //    options.rules.myRule = function () {/*...*/ };
                //    options.messages.myRule = "message";
                //    validator.setOptions(options);
                //},
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "PerformanceRateValue",
                        title: "PerformanceRateValue",
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains",
                                suggestionOperator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        field: "PerformanceRateDescEn",
                        title: "PerformanceRateDescEn",
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains",
                                suggestionOperator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        field: "PerformanceRateDescAr",
                        title: "PerformanceRateDescAr",
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains",
                                suggestionOperator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        template: ColorPerformanceRate,
                        field: "Color",
                        title: "Color",

                        editor: ColorEditor,
                        filterable: {
                            cell: {
                                operator: "contains",
                                suggestionOperator: "contains"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        command: [
                            { name: "edit", template: "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default k-grid-edit' onclick='' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit' ><i class='fas fa-pencil'></i></a>" },
                            { name: "destroy", template: "<a class='btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-danger' onclick='setPerformanceRateFadeInOutStatus(0);RunLoadingWithoutVaildation();return confirmmessage();' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Remove' ><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>" },
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
            d.table.kendoSortable({
                filter: ">tbody >tr",
                hint: $.noop,
                cursor: "move",
                placeholder: function (element) {
                    return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
                },
                container: "#gvPerformanceRate tbody",
                change: function (e) {
                    var skip = d.dataSource.skip(),
                        oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
                        newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
                        data = d.dataSource.data(),
                        dataItem = d.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

                    d.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
                    d.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
                }
            });
        });


        var ColorPerformanceRate = function (e) {
            return "<i class='fas fa-star StarRate float-left' style='color:" + e.Color + "'></i>"
        };
        function ColorEditor(container, options) {
            $('<input name="' + options.field + '" required data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: true,
                    valuePrimitive: true,
                    optionLabel: "-- Select -- ",
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    dataSource: Colors
                });
            $("<span class='k-invalid-msg' data-for='" + options.field + "'></span>").appendTo(container);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just move schema inside dataSource